# Send/Receive text over socket (objective c - total newbie)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am not an Objective C programmer but inherited this project as I have a little experience with C++ and Java Script. I'm trying to create this in X-Code to be used on an IOS device.  What I want to do is create a TCP/IP socket and send a simple line of text, then wait for a reply and parse it.

The code below I think does create the connection, but I can't figure out how to send a string of text or the structure.

I think I need to somehow incorporate the text I want to send in writeStream.
I've looked at the references [Apple - Using sockets & streams](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html), [CFWriteStream Reference](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFWriteStreamRef/CFWriteStreamRef.pdf) (both are a bit  over my head with structures, data types etc.)

I also see libraries to create the TCP/IP sockets but think they may be overkill for what I'm trying to do.

**I Think this does create the socket but then not sure how to send or receive characters**

```
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"192.168.1.77",(uint) 5200 , NULL, &writeStream);
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream open];
    
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self
                                           selector:@selector(SocketFail)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
}


- (void) SocketFail {
    [outputStream close];
    [outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
    LastMessage=@"Could not connect";
    
}



- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
    [theStream close];
    [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    
    switch (streamEvent) {
        case 1:
            LastMessage=@"Connected";
            break;
        default:
            LastMessage =(@"Could not establish\n connection with host");
    }

}
```

Some gentle hand holding help with the next step would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest you search for and read through a few tutorials -- most of the ones you find these days will be for Swift, but the concepts (and much of the code) will be the same. Here's a good one to start with: https://www.raywenderlich.com/3437391-real-time-communication-with-streams-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: Probably better if you just use 3rd party library websocket like SocketRocket. Saves a lot of time reinventing the wheel.